# Get Retweets for Tweets via Twitter4J with Java/Maven

Tags: java, neo4j, twitter4j

I am working at a project which should fetch Tweets, Retweets and Followers from Twitter via Twitter4J and then save them to a local Neo4J DB.

At the moment I try to figure out how to get the retweets to a tweet which I fetched. 
In my result I find something which is called "retweetedStatus" as Retweets??
But it's only one even if there are more Retweets.
I also tried to get them by using ResponseList and getRetweets(), but the List is always empty.

Here is the part of the class which fetches the Tweets and should fetch the Retweets:

```
try {
        Query query = new Query("#" + input);
        QueryResult result;
        result = twitter.search(query);
        tweets = result.getTweets();

        System.out.println(result);
        //Get the result and convert it into JSONArray to safe it to DB
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray arrayTweets = object.getJSONArray("tweets");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayTweets.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jSONObject = (JSONObject) arrayTweets.get(i);
            reTweet = twitter.getRetweets(jSONObject.getLong("id"));
            System.out.println("Retweet ResponseList: "+reTweet);

            if (jSONObject.has("retweetedStatus")) {
                JSONObject retweet = jSONObject.getJSONObject("retweetedStatus");
                getReTweets(retweet);
                reTweets.put(retweet);

            }else{
                System.out.println("tweet has no retweet");
            }
            String textTweets = jSONObject.toString();

            System.out.println("Search Textfile " + i + " successful saved");
            Files.write(Paths.get("./searchTweets" + i + ".txt"), textTweets.getBytes());


        }
```

Afterwards I create Nodes with Neo4J and want to relate the retweets to the tweets which is not yet working perfectly. Here is one part of the code:

```
//Safe the retrieved data to own Neo4j DB
void safeToDb(JSONArray tweet,JSONArray retweet, String from) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, JSONException {

    System.out.println("||||||||||||||||||||||||");
    System.out.println("Started to safe data to DB");
    System.out.println("|||||||||||||||||||||||||");

    //Here the transaction happens
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
        Label myLabel = TWEET;
        System.out.println("||||||||||||||||||||||||");
        System.out.println("Transaction started");
        System.out.println("|||||||||||||||||||||||||");
        // Database operations go here
        //Create Nodes of all the retrieved Data
        for (int i = 0; i < tweet.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jSONObjectTweet = (JSONObject) tweet.get(i);
            String textTweet = jSONObjectTweet.toString();

            System.out.println("DB Tweet Textfile " + i + " successful saved");
            Files.write(Paths.get("./safeTweetToDb" + i + ".txt"), textTweet.getBytes());

            createEntityTweets(jSONObjectTweet);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < retweet.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jSONObjectReTweet = (JSONObject) retweet.get(i);
            String textReTweet = jSONObjectReTweet.toString();

            System.out.println("DB Retweet Textfile " + i + " successful saved");
            Files.write(Paths.get("./safeRetweetToDb" + i + ".txt"), textReTweet.getBytes());

            createEntityRetweets(jSONObjectReTweet);



        }
        relationship = this.tweet.createRelationshipTo(this.retweet, RelationshipTypes.IS_RETWEET_OF);

        //relationship.setProperty("message", "brave Neo4j ");
        tx.success();
    }
```

Comment: The `getRetweets` API will return 100 retweets as a list of `Status`. `ResponseList<Status>` of the passed in `statusId` see [here](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TweetsResources.html#getRetweets-long-). Is `jSONObject.getLong("id")` is the status id? and what is the type of `reTweet` in `reTweet = twitter.getRetweets(jSONObject.getLong("id"));`

Comment: reTweet is type of ResponseList<Status> 
And the id should be the Tweets ID which I get from the twitter API.
Here is a short part of the returning JSON:

"id": 861279463312465921,
"lang": "es",
"favorited": false,
"displayTextRangeEnd": -1,

Comment: Okay. There are two retweets for this tweet id `861279463312465921`. But you are getting only one after calling `twitter.getRetweets`?

Comment: Via getRetweets I get an empty list so far. With twitter4J.getTweets I get in the response a retweetedStatus but that's only one

Comment: I fixed the problem.
I found out that I can just use the returned Status to get things like Id and so on. With this ID I can get the Retweeds without problems. Furthermore the code is a lot more easy and understandable. Thanks for your help pete ;)